# View won't pick up post

Tags: django, jquery, django-views, html-post

Can someone tell me why the following view won't pick up a POST request:

```
# Loads all the latest phone numbers for the models.py file
def client_phones_form_view(request, clientKEY):
    try:
        i_clientKEY = int(clientKEY)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    phones = []
    # Populates a list with the latest phone numbers for ALL types of phone
    for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES:
        try:
            phones.append(ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY, phone_type=k).latest('id'))
        except ClientPhone.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formPhone = ClientPhoneForm(request.POST)
        if formPhone.is_valid() and formPhone.number.clean(formPhone.number):
            c = Client.objects.get(id=i_clientKEY)
            formPhone.CustomSave(c, request.user)
            return render_to_response(...)
        else:
            return render_to_response(...)
    else:
        formPhone = ClientPhoneForm()
        return render_to_response(...)
```

I know when I submit the form it's reloading, but it always reloads the bottom `render_to_response`

**EDIT:**

The javascript looks something like this:

```
$( "#newPhoneDialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add New Phone Number": function() {
            var bValid = true;
            //alert($('#id_number').val()+" - "+$('#id_phone_type').val());

            bValid = bValid && checkNumberLength( phoneNumber, "the phone number", 11, 15 );

            bValid = bValid && checkNumberRegexp( phoneNumber, /^([0-9])|( \t)+$/, "The phone number may only consist of numbers and spaces");

            if ( bValid ) {
                $('.error').hide(); // hide the error div
                $('.success').hide(); // hide the success div
                $('.info').hide(); // hide the information div
                $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: $('#newPhoneForm').serialize(), // get the form data
                    type: 'POST', // GET or POST
                    url: 'client/form/phones/1/', // the file to call
                    success: function(response) { // on success..
                        $('#clientPhonesForm').html(response); // update the main phones DIV
                    }
                });
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                //return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
            }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            // reloads the phone div because re-selecting the first item in the options doesn't work
            $('#clientPhonesForm').load('{% url client.views.client_phones_form_view clientKEY %}');
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        // reloads the phone div because re-selecting the first item in the options doesn't work
        //$('#clientPhonesForm').load('{% url client.views.client_phones_form_view clientKEY %}');
    }
});
```

And HTML something like this:

```
<div id="newPhoneDialog" title="Create New Phone Number">
        Please enter a valid phone number:
    <div id="container">
        <form action="{% url client.views.client_phones_form_view clientKEY %}" method="POST" id="newPhoneForm">
            <table>
            {% for field in formPhone %}
            <tr><td>{{ field.label_tag }}</td><td>{{ field }}</td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Maybe this question would be better if it said *'How do I (jquery ajax) submit a form when a button is clicked'*

Comment: Can you please tell me how many requests are coming through in the dev server or logging attempts? When you click the button, what happens? Does the dev server register a POST and then reload the page with a GET? Does it register a GET and the page does not reload?

Comment: The dev server only shows on POST request

Comment: when I comment out `formPhone.number.clean(formPhone.number)` everything seems to work fine. `formPhone.number` uses `UKPhoneNumberField()` from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1207/

Comment: That means the view is making it to that clean line, which means it is detecting `request.method == 'POST'`! That means your problem is strictly that `if` condition: `if valid and formPhone.number.clean()`. Your question makes it sound like only the bottom-most `render` function is being called and django is ignoring the `if request.method` line. Why do you even need that line? If UKPhoneNumberField() is defined as a part of your form, `form.is_valid()` would return `False` if the field validation failed.

Comment: the dev server started chucking a `Http 500` as well so that's why I put the cleaning of the number in a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seemed to be the answer. Whether it is correct or not I don't know:

```
# Loads all the latest phone numbers for the models.py file
def client_phones_form_view(request, clientKEY):
    try:
        i_clientKEY = int(clientKEY)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    phones = []
    # Populates a list with the latest phone numbers for ALL types of phone
    for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES:
        try:
            phones.append(ClientPhone.objects.filter(...).latest('id'))
        except ClientPhone.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formPhone = ClientPhoneForm(request.POST)
        if formPhone.is_valid():
            try:
                n = formPhone.cleaned_data['number']
            except ValidationError:
                return render_to_response(...)
            c = Client.objects.get(id=i_clientKEY)
            formPhone.CustomNumberSave(c, n, request.user)
            return render_to_response(...)
        else:
            return render_to_response(...)

    else:
        formPhone = ClientPhoneForm()
        return render_to_response(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a bullet proof condition right there: `if request.method == 'POST'` so I would start looking at why you are not generating a `POST` request, not the view.

Can you make sure that you're posting from your form?

`<form method="post">`

Is the dev server registering a POST request ? Should say `"GET /..."` or `"POST /..."`

---

Update: OK so it's an ajax request form. There was another person on SO recently that had a similar issue because the AJAX request was triggering the original form as a GET request.

I see you commented out `return false` -- could that be the problem? Actually nevermind, I don't think a dialogs buttons would interfere.

More importantly then: what is the dev server recording? A POST then a GET? A single GET?

Comment: I tried the following http://pastebin.com/few79mwX and it still uses the last `render_to_response` :(

Comment: By outputting `request.method` I have found it is a POST method